# How can i combine 4 API controllers to a single controller in asp.net core 2.1 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm currently doing a project in asp.net core 2.1 MVC in visual studio 2017. And i'm having a total of 8 controllers in my project and to simplify things i want to combine 4 controllers into one single controller so that the project looks simple. All those 4 controllers are API controllers. I'm a newbie to this, so please help me. How can i do that? One of my API controller is attached for reference, PFA.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]        
[ApiController]        
public class CandidateKeywordController : ControllerBase        
{        
    [Route("{query}")]        
    public IEnumerable<string> Get(string query)        
    {    
        KeywordGenerator keywordGen = new KeywordGenerator();    
        return keywordGen.GetCandidateKeywords(query);    

    }    
}
```

Comment: add more details about your controllers, put some code, describe what kind of shared methods you have etc...

Comment: @ThomasMartin, please edit your question and put the code in there instead of putting it in the comment.

Comment: Sorry. its added

Comment: What problem are you experiencing, other than copy-pasting code from the 4 controllers to one?

Comment: so are you saying that it is just easy as copy/paste all those contents from all those 4 controllers to one? @Tsahi Asher

Comment: That's a start, and then you should make sure you don't have conflicting routings. I'm more experienced with ASP.NET MVC (not Core), but that's where would have started.

Comment: Copy paste wont work fully as you will face conflicting routes.you need to define routes on each controller method.

Comment: So actually what all contents should i copy/paste to the new controller?

Comment: Why would you need four controllers in one? the aim of `OOP` is to keep code simple and reusable, are you not considering that? if they are all `APIControllers` why not just copy the methods you are exposing as `API` to one of the `APIControllers` and change your `Route` parameters

Comment: Yeah i want to make the code look simple. Because im having around 10 controllers in the project and it looks bulky thats why i want to combine those controllers as one